# NSLinkAttributeName not clickable for unicode font

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am using a UITextView backed by NSTextStorage. The below code for attributed string with links works well for English language.

```
let linkURL = NSURL(string: "reference://\(pageno)")
var pagenoAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, pagenoAttrString.length)
pagenoAttrString.beginEditing()
pagenoAttrString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: linkURL!, range: range)
pagenoAttrString.endEditing()
```

The same code does not seem to work when I am switching language other than English. I do get the links in blue colour but it is not clickable.